# Plugable Email Templating solution for C#

Tags: email, templates, template-engine

Is anyone aware of a plugable Email Templating solution for C#?  I've grown weary of having to roll my own each project and I imagine there are more robust solutions out there.  It should support HTML/non-HTML and allow for tokens (e.g. USERNAME is replaced with a configurable value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ComponentForge Mail Merge Suite is a
>   set of flexible and easy-to-use .NET
>   components for generating dynamic
>   email content with DynamicTemplate.

http://www.componentforge.net/mailmergesuite.aspx

If you're looking for a free hack, OpenOffice claims to be capable of this:

http://internet.cybermesa.com/~aaron_w/OOo_email_merge/OOo_email_merge.html

Comment: Component Forge is IMHO not a good tip. They stole almost all of their components from other vendors. For example ComponentForge MailMergeSuite suite is illegally built on top of Rebex Secure Mail. For details of this scam see http://cheated.by.safabyte.net/evidence.aspx